# Why does "Update to Match Selection" change the selection in Word?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, styles

In Word on OSX, I'm trying to update a style.

Here's how I usually do it:

- I select a paragraph
- I select the style from the style sidebar
- I modify the paragraph
- I select the paragraph again
- I select the drop-down arrow on the style in the style sidebar
- I select "Update to match selection"

In most cases, this just changes the style to match the paragraph I've selected.

But I'm occasionally running into a problem where clicking "Update" actually reformats the paragraph into a different style altogether.

Any idea what's going wrong?

**Edit:** I'm running Version 16.16.9, though I've had this problem for years across different versions, on both Mac and PC.

The styles I'm trying to do are a set of nesting numbered lists.

The first one ("NumberedList1") is based on the Normal style, but numbered and indented about a half inch. I have another style ("NumberedList2") based on NumberedList1, but then I slide it over to indent another quarter inch and restart the numbering.

When I do that, the paragraph I just edited snaps back to NumberedList1.

Comment: What version of Word for the Mac are you running?

Comment: Not enough info to make a determination. Need to know the properties of the style.

Comment: Thanks for following up. I've added more information in the question.

Comment: You must have another style associated with outline numbering for that level. Updating to match will not fix the problem. I would suggest building the list from scratch using outline numbering (https://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html?p=1768).